# Select whole row and insert it into table_2

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, join, insert

Is it possible to select whole row from `table_1` (without autoincrement ID) and insert it into another table `table_2` which has the same relational scheme as `table_1` (the same columns)?

I can do that using for example `Python` but the table has too much rows to do write a code for that.

So this is the example:
table_1:

```
id | name | age | sex | degree 
1  | Pate | 98  | it  | doc 
2  | Ken  | 112 | male| -
```

table_2:

```
id | name | age | sex | degree
```

SQLite3:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id=2);
```

RESULT:
table_2:

```
id | name | age | sex | degree
1  | Ken  | 112 | male| -
```

EDIT:

If this is not possible, it could be done including id so the table_2 would look like:

```
id | name | age | sex | degree
2  | Ken  | 112 | male| -
```

Answer (score 0):

The [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) indeed has a form that inserts each row returned by a SELECT. However, that SELECT is not a subquery, so you have to omit the parentheses around it, and when you're not inserting all columns, you have to specifiy which columns to use:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_2 (name, age, sex, degree)
SELECT name, age, sex, degree
FROM table_1
WHERE id = 2;
```